# Correctly show mapping association using inheritance

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

Im working with entities inheritances using doctrine [Class Table Inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance).

I have a base entity **BaseEntity**.

Then I have **FirstEntity** and **SecondEntity** that extends the **BaseEntity**.

In other hands, I have a **StandardEntity** that have a mapping association of *OneToMany* **BaseEntity** named *baseEntities*.

In the view page of an **StandardEntity**, it should also show the list of **BaseEntity** that is related to this one.

But I've got some trouble with that.

**First error**:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: nl2br() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given").
```

**First solution**:  I forced the type of the property to *association*.

```xml
- { property: baseEntities, type: association }
```

**I've got a second error**:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined index: targetEntity").
```

But if I set the type to *array*, I get the correct item list but there is just simple text. I would like to have links that link to the related entity - **FirstEntity** or **SecondEntity** - view page.

```xml
- { property: baseEntities, type: array }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to add the type "association" and type_options the class of the entity in question to also have the links, for example, here I use my class Tag

```
 { property: 'tags', type: 'association', type_options: 'App\Entity\Tag' }
```